# Multiple dropdown menus opening all at once

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

I built a "dropdown menu" that allows my content to be hidden until onclick event with HTML, CSS, and JS. However, the menus all open at the same time when one menu is clicked. I want only one menu to open at a time.

here's my code so far:

HTML

```
<div class="hidden">
  <button id="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Title of Section</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="hidden-content">
  <div class="article-list">
              
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I have multiple of these "hidden" divs, each named the same thing so the same effects work on them in my CSS. There's about 5 of them I believe. I put the hidden content inside "hidden-content" and have removed the irrelevant sections that don't matter to the code question. If there's something I'm missing, let me know and I'll do my best to update.

CSS

```
.dropbtn {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Turret Road';
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--default5);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--defaultAccent1), var(--default3Muted));
  box-shadow: var(--default1) 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--defaultAccent1), var(--default1));
}

.hidden {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hidden a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--defaultAccent1), var(--default1));
}

.hidden-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--default3Muted);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hidden-content a {
  color: var(--default1);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

The CSS all seems to be working, but the JS requires a "show" element that I have not put into the HTML at all. It still functions without it. Do I need to add the "show" element to my HTML?

JS

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should update your html to show "multiple of these hidden divs". As-is, your example doesn't show the problem you've presented.

Comment: Additionally, what's this about? `id="myFunction()"`? An id should be a string; it won't execute that function.

Comment: @mykaf Seems like a typo for `onclick="myFunction()"`, probably just a copying error.

Comment: I don't see anything that will show multiple elements. `myFunction()` shows one div, and the `window.onclick` function hides all the dropdowns, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: There's no need for the `if` statement. Removing a class that doesn't exist has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written your code to make the menu display and disappear when the button is clicked:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("display-articles-button");

if (buttons !== null) {
  for (var button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      var menuElements = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");

      if (menuElements !== null) {
        for (var menuElement of menuElements) {
          console.log(menuElement);

          var attribute = menuElement.getAttribute("data-show");

          if (attribute !== null) {
            if (attribute == "true" || attribute == true) {
              menuElement.style.display = "none";
              menuElement.setAttribute("data-show", false);
            } else {
              menuElement.style.display = "block";
              menuElement.setAttribute("data-show", true);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
  width: 220px;
  height: 128px;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="display-articles-button" type="button">Title of Section</button>
  <div class="menu" data-show="false">
    <article>
      <p>Test</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <p>Test</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Full code sample:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <style>
            .menu {
                display: none;
                width: 220px;
                height: 128px;

                background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
                border-radius: 7px;
                padding: 7px;
                margin-top: 7px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="button-container">
            <button class="display-articles-button" type="button">Title of Section</button>
            <div class="menu" data-show="false">
                <article>
                    <p>Test</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <p>Test</p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("display-articles-button");

            if(buttons !== null) {
                for(var button of buttons) {
                    button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                        var menuElements = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");

                        if(menuElements !== null) {
                            for(var menuElement of menuElements) {
                                console.log(menuElement);
                                
                                var attribute = menuElement.getAttribute("data-show");

                                if(attribute !== null) {
                                    if(attribute == "true" || attribute == true) {
                                        menuElement.style.display = "block";
                                        menuElement.setAttribute("data-show", false);

                                        console.log(menuElement + " is not visible.");
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        menuElement.style.display = "none";
                                        menuElement.setAttribute("data-show", true);

                                        console.log(menuElement + " is visible.");                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use a Stack Snippet instead of linking to jsfiddle.

Comment: @Barmar Created a Stack Snippet.